# How to use for loop on pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy in reverse order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object,iter_gb contains customer Itinerary. The sample data looks like. After Itinerary it contains 6 columns, those columns are not important.

```
Customer_id YEAR    Itinerary A1, B1, ...
38915672    2015    B12345
38915672    2012    B12345
38915672    2012    B25431
38915672    2012    B25431
38915672    2012    B25431
38915672    2012    B25431
38915672    2012    B25431
38915672    2012    B36789
38915672    2012    B36789
38915672    2012    B36789
38915672    2012    B36789
38915672    2012    B36789
38915672    2012    B86451
38915672    2012    B86451
38915672    2012    B86451
38915672    2012    B86451
38915672    2011    B86451
```

I would like to read this using `for loop` in reverse order.

For example for loop will start from last row store all the rows of `B86451` in a data frame & then 
`B36789` & so on.

how to do that in python 3.x?

Comment: can you post expected output?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need first reverse `DataFrame` and then loop:

```
for i, x in df[::-1].groupby('Itinerary', sort=False):
    print (x)
    Customer_id  YEAR Itinerary
16     38915672  2011    B86451
15     38915672  2012    B86451
14     38915672  2012    B86451
13     38915672  2012    B86451
12     38915672  2012    B86451
    Customer_id  YEAR Itinerary
11     38915672  2012    B36789
10     38915672  2012    B36789
9      38915672  2012    B36789
8      38915672  2012    B36789
7      38915672  2012    B36789
   Customer_id  YEAR Itinerary
6     38915672  2012    B25431
5     38915672  2012    B25431
4     38915672  2012    B25431
3     38915672  2012    B25431
2     38915672  2012    B25431
   Customer_id  YEAR Itinerary
1     38915672  2012    B12345
0     38915672  2015    B12345
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, my df is already a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object. I don't need to do any further groupby with 'Itinerary'

Comment: @ChristinaHughes - How is create your `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object?

Comment: Hi @jezrael,it's using this code `df = passenger.groupby(['Itinerary'])`

Comment: @ChristinaHughes - so try `df = passenger.iloc[::-1].groupby(['Itinerary'])`

Comment: @ChristinaHughes and then `for i, x in df:`